# How can I use csquotes with LaTeX export in Org-mode?

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

When using [csquotes](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) quotation marks are added by csquotes according to context. This is done by marking up quotation with the `\enquote` macro, i.e. as `\enquote{text}`.

When exporting to LaTeX from Org-mode quotation marks are marked up as ``` `` ``` and `''`, e.g. as ``` ``text'' ```.

Can Org-mode export to LaTeX with quotations marked up by `\enquote`?

I found http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/43689 where such a feature is being planned but I do not understand whether it was implemented.

---

On a related note there is [integration of csquotes in AUCTeX](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Quotes.html). The integration is that when a document loads csquotes then <kbd>"</kbd> is expanded to `\enquote{` and `}` respectively. This is not what I am asking for but there might be bits of code that can be interested in setting up Org-mode to export quotations marked up by `\enquote`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following that thread to the end and then looking at the changelog for the 7.7 (see [Headline for version 7.7](http://orgmode.org/Changes.html)) release I find that they have added a variable `org-latex-export-quotes`.  I'm not entirely sure how this would have to be customized, but I suspect it would have to end up something as follows:

Original (included since it only appears in 7.7 and I believe you're running 7.6):

```lisp
(defcustom org-export-latex-quotes
  '(("fr" ("\\(\\s-\\|[[(]\\)\"" . "«~") ("\\(\\S-\\)\"" . "~»") ("\\(\\s-\\|(\\)'" . "'"))
    ("en" ("\\(\\s-\\|[[(]\\)\"" . "``") ("\\(\\S-\\)\"" . "''") ("\\(\\s-\\|(\\)'" . "`")))
  "Alist for quotes to use when converting english double-quotes.

The CAR of each item in this alist is the language code.
The CDR of each item in this alist is a list of three CONS:
- the first CONS defines the opening quote;
- the second CONS defines the closing quote;
- the last CONS defines single quotes.

For each item in a CONS, the first string is a regexp
for allowed characters before/after the quote, the second
string defines the replacement string for this quote."
```

To:

```lisp
(setq org-export-latex-quotes
  '(("en" ("\\(\\s-\\|[[(]\\)\"" . "\\enquote{") ("\\(\\S-\\)\"" . "}") ("\\(\\s-\\|(\\)'" . "`"))))
```

I just tested this and it does perform as expected.  The sample file:

```
* test
this is a test of "this"
```

exports as (preamble omitted):

```latex
\section{test}
\label{sec-1}

this is a test of \enquote{this}
```

I do not know if it is possible to easily add this feature within 7.6, the easier solution would likely be to upgrade.  Otherwise the easier solution in 7.6 would likely be to create a custom link (see: [Org Tutorials](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-export.html#sec-10-3)).  This would not be as fast but does provide the desired results within the features provided by 7.6.

Comment: It is nice that it is implemented in a new version. I am not that good with elisp so that I could determine whether [the diff](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blobdiff;f=lisp/org-latex.el;h=34ceca9041732ec47d5947d50c61a928420dc8f5;hp=e1c85ce581a3a5093eb3b419cf4364671b6d2388;hb=2b9afb9e63d2fd60a3bb09e33c9d4abb01586339;hpb=9fc6daa3d28cb1dcec87fcd769997b8f121e286c) can be backported to 7.6 easily.

Comment: Perhaps the solution would be to install `emacs-snapshot`?  It would give you emacs 24 pretest (which is stable) as well as bump org up to 7.8. (See: http://www.mikeyboldt.com/2011/11/30/install-emacs-24-in-ubuntu/ for a simple procedure)

Comment: Is is possible to extend this solution to export `'test'` as `\enquote*{test}`?

Comment: I don't believe so.  The logic looks for opening double quotes, closing double quotes and single quotes.  There is no distinction between opening and closing single quotes so there would be no way to differentiate the characters used on both ends.

Comment: That is sad. I would offer a bounty to a solution that could add such functionality.

Comment: You'd be better off asking for this on the mailing-list.  It probably requires modification of the exporter to be able to incorporate that change.

Answer (score 5):

@N.N. and others, the new org-mode export function in org 8.0 has a list named `org-export-smart-quotes-alist`. You can add the following to your init.el and it will turn regular `"` double quotes into `enquote{}`, and `'` single quotes into `enquote*{}`.

```
(add-to-list 'org-export-smart-quotes-alist 
             '("am"
               (primary-opening   :utf-8 "“" :html "&ldquo;" :latex "\\enquote{"  :texinfo "``")
               (primary-closing   :utf-8 "”" :html "&rdquo;" :latex "}"           :texinfo "''")
               (secondary-opening :utf-8 "‘" :html "&lsquo;" :latex "\\enquote*{" :texinfo "`")
               (secondary-closing :utf-8 "’" :html "&rsquo;" :latex "}"           :texinfo "'")
               (apostrophe        :utf-8 "’" :html "&rsquo;")))
```

A word of warning: if you want this to work in your org file's language, make sure you either have `org-export-default-language` set to `"am"` (or whatever you choose to use in the above form), or you put the appropriate `#+LANGUAGE: am` line at the top of your org file. If you don't, the org exporter won't call the above.