# How to handle quotes in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

How do I handle quotes in org-mode? Similar to the `>` in stackoverflow.

Comment: If you mean to handle the LaTeX output you could [use the LaTeX package `csquotes` to control quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9053276/789593).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The only built-in mechanism I can think of is `#+begin_quote` [blocks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/org.html#Paragraphs), which may be meant [for export](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/45458). I personally either leave `>` from emails, or use [emacs boxes](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BoxQuote).

Answer (score 4):

You can customize the CSS of `blockquote` element to get a nicer formatting.

Why `blockquote` element? If you use browser's inspect function to inspect the quote block, you can find its style is controlled by `blockquote` element.

Below is an example of SO-like quote block, you can find the configuration by inspecting the styles of `blockquote` in SO.

```
#+BEGIN_EXPORT html
<style>
blockquote {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF8DC;
    border-left: 2px solid #ffeb8e;
    border-left-color: rgb(255, 228, 102);
    display: block;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 40px;
    margin-inline-end: 40px;
}
</style>
#+END_EXPORT

#+BEGIN_QUOTE
By customizing the style of blockquote element, we get a SO-like style quote block in org-mode.
#+END_QUOTE
```

It renders like

[image]

Comment: Very nice.  However, the `margin-bottom` line does not seem to work in my case (actually, I'd like a `margin-left`).  `padding-left` seems to work though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:`

I've only ever needed to use it when quoting org code itself.

Instead, use `#+BEGIN_SRC`, which gives you the chance to do very neat remote-highlighting of code in HTML output.

See the excellent manual for that.

Comment: Should it be `~:'~` ?