# How to export inline quotations from emacs org mode to latex csquotes syntax?

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I would like to export inline quotations in an org-document to \enquote{} commands. The csquotes package then ensures French quotation marks « » are used in the resulting pdf document.

I am well aware this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053276/how-can-i-use-csquotes-with-latex-export-in-org-mode/19332031#19332031?newreg=62c58f7e9e4f482db46cecf1b289da77) - and that solutions have been suggested by @Jonathan Leech-Pepin and @Christophe Poile. I tried all solutions suggested, without success. I would like to avoid (1) hardcoding the correct quotation marks or (2) using the latex command in my org document. OSX 10.15.5, emacs 26.2, org 9.2.5.

Org document header:

```
#+Title: GS
#+AUTHOR: HDV
#+SEQ_TODO: 
#+TAGS: 
#+STARTUP: indent
#+LANGUAGE: fr
#+LaTeX_CLASS: article
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [a4paper,11pt,twoside]
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{ae,lmodern}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[french]{babel}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{graphicx} 
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
```

Exported latex preamble:

```
    % Created 2020-07-07 Tue 20:45
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ae,lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes} 
\author{}
\date{\today}
\title{}
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={},
 pdftitle={},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 26.2 (Org mode 9.2.5)}, 
 pdflang={French}}
\begin{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `csquotes` or `\enquote{}` to get guillemets; there is `smart quote` support out of the box in Org mode. The following suffices:

```
#+OPTIONS: ':t
#+LANGUAGE: fr
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[french]{babel}

* foo

As somebody once said:
  
"You cannot explain anything to a stone."
```

You turn on `smart quotes`, set the  `#+LANGUAGE` to `fr` to select the french style of smart quotes and then let `babel` figure it out. The TeX file produced looks like this (only the significant parts are shown):

```latex
...
\usepackage[french]{babel}
...
\begin{document}

...

\section{foo}
\label{sec:orgd0ec1fc}

As somebody once said:

\og You cannot explain anything to a stone.\fg{}
\end{document}
```

If you *really* want `\enquote`, you can modify the value of `org-export-smart-quotes-alist`. I think the best way is to duplcate the current section for `fr`, modify it for your purposes and add it to the beginning of the alist where it is going to shadow the existing entry:

```el
  (setq fr-quotes '("fr"
            (primary-opening :utf-8 "« " :html "&laquo;&nbsp;" :latex "\\enquote{" :texinfo "@guillemetleft{}@tie{}")
            (primary-closing :utf-8 " »" :html "&nbsp;&raquo;" :latex "}" :texinfo "@tie{}@guillemetright{}")
            (secondary-opening :utf-8 "« " :html "&laquo;&nbsp;" :latex "\\\enquote{" :texinfo "@guillemetleft{}@tie{}")
            (secondary-closing :utf-8 " »" :html "&nbsp;&raquo;" :latex "\\}" :texinfo "@tie{}@guillemetright{}")
            (apostrophe :utf-8 "’" :html "&rsquo;"))

  (add-to-list 'org-export-smart-quotes-alist fr-quotes)
```

As you can see I changed the opening and closing quotes for `LaTeX` to use `\enquote{` to open and `}` to close. Adding it to the front of the list allows you to get rid of it quickly if you want to go back to the default:

```el
(setq org-export-smart-quotes-alist (cdr org-export-smart-quotes-alist))
```

gets rid of the first entry (the added "fr" entry) allowing the default "fr" entry to be seen. You should probably do `C-h v org-export-smart-quotes-alist` and look at its value carefully.

Then the Org mode file becomes:

```
#+OPTIONS: ':t
#+LANGUAGE: fr
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[french]{babel}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}

* foo

As somebody once said:
  
"You cannot explain anything to a stone."
```

and the resulting tex file looks like this (again, only the significant parts are shown):

```tex
...
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
...
\begin{document}
...
\section{foo}
\label{sec:orgb8fcb36}

As somebody once said:

\enquote{You cannot explain anything to a stone.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It works like a charm. PS: from a Latex perspective I would prefer `csquotes` over `"´` or something like that. Its clearer and more flexible. For example, it offers you the possibility to change the style of specific quotes in a mulilingual document: `\usepackage[autostyle,german=guillemets,norwegian=quotes]{csquotes}` (taken from the `csquotes` docs, p. 4).

Answer (score 0):

I used to use the following code to convert @xxx@ to \hl{xxx} (using the soul LaTeX package). You might be able to adapt this to convert "xxx" to \enquote{xxx}?

```
** convert @highlighted@ text on export to ~\hl{highlighted}~
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (defun esf/latex-filter-highlight (text backend info)
    "Convert @...@ to \hl{...} in LaTeX export."
    (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex)
      (replace-regexp-in-string "@\\([^@]+\\)@" "\\\\hl{\\1}" text)))

  (add-to-list 'org-export-filter-plain-text-functions
               'esf/latex-filter-highlight)
#+end_src
```